# Unity2017、プレハブが作られない

Tags: unity3d

MMDモーションをUnityに取り込んでアニメーションさせたい
参考動画：https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kaum5g4jgns

参考動画では9:50で`Process`を実行してプレハブが作成されてるが、実行環境でプレバブが作成されなくて困っています。
Unityちゃんのモーションは再生することはできました。
参考：http://qiita.com/SatoruNoda/items/e44762ab9f97de756c66

実行環境： OS X 10.10、Unity2017

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

僕も同じでした。

原因として考えられるのはMMD4Mecanimの、Editarのファイルを見てみると、Unity4とUnity5の
ファイルがさらにあると思いますが、**Unity2017のファイルはない**ということです。

したがって、MMD4Mecanimは、まだUnity2017.1には対応していないということになります。

Unity2017.verが出るのを待つか、Blenderを使ってPMXファイルなどをblendファイルに
変換するのもいいかもしれません。

僕はその方法でMMDファイルを変換してunityに入れることに成功しました！
※一部のデータは、テクスチャなどが適切にunityに読み込められない場合もたまにあるらしいので、
 そういう場合に陥った時は、別にテクスチャを読み込んでマテリアルにし、適用してあげるのもいいかもしれませんね。